# AutoFac equivalent of this ninject command/function

Tags: autofac, autofac-configuration, autofactory

In Ninject i can configure a container like the mentioned below, What is the Autofac equivalent for the **"Highlighted ones"**?

Currently i am trying to achieve the same using AutoFac, any help is much appreciated.

```
 public class NinjectAdapter : IContainerAdapter
 {
    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    public NinjectAdapter(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    **public void Register(Type service, Type implementation)
    {
        _kernel.Bind(service).To(implementation);
    }**

    **public void Register(Type service, Type implementation, Type conditionType)
    {
        _kernel.Bind(service).To(implementation).WhenInjectedInto(conditionType);
    }**

    **public void Register(Type service, Type implementation, string named)
    {
        _kernel.Bind(service).To(implementation).Named(named);
    }**

    **public void RegisterSingleton(Type service, Type implementation)
    {
        _kernel.Bind(service).To(implementation).InSingletonScope();
    }**

    **public void RegisterInScope(Type service, Type implementation)
    {
        _kernel.Bind(service).To(implementation).InScope(scope => HttpContext.Current);
    }**


    **public void RegisterInstance(Type service, object instance)
    {
        _kernel.Bind(service).ToConstant(instance);
    }**

    **public void RegisterInstance(Type service, object instance, string named)
    {
        _kernel.Bind(service).ToConstant(instance).Named(named);
    }**
}
```